# How to get rid of empty data in Craig Stunz's demo application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I download Craig Stunz's demo application from [his blog](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/17/38229/) and run it from Visual Studio 2010. The result is the grid with its UI but no rows. What should I do to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question and it was answered in the comments of the post.

> Change the code like this if you used
>   ASP.NET MVC 2
>
> return Json(model.ToJqGridData(page,
>   rows, null, search, new[] {
>   "IntProperty", "StringProperty",
>   "DateProperty" }),
>   **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet**); }
>
> NOTE : HomeController.cs

So, again you need to change the code in the controller's action that return the Json object as below.

```
return Json(
  model.ToJqGridData(
    page, rows, null, search, 
    new[] { "IntProperty", "StringProperty", "DateProperty" }),
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
);
```

I didn't test this. Please confirm if that helps!